# How to start HostFactory.New topshelf service

Tags: .net, topshelf

Here is example of creating `HostFactory` with `New` method and declaring service: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#simple-service

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.Service<MyService>();
});

// Service implements the ServiceControl methods directly and has a default constructor
class MyService : ServiceControl
{}
```

But i can't figure out, how to start this service immediately (like `HostFactory.Run(...)`)?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found an answer:

`public static Host New(Action<HostConfigurator> configureCallback)`

returns `Host` which implements:

```
public interface Host
{
    TopshelfExitCode Run();
}
```

So, if'd you like to start your service, you have to call `Run` like this:

`HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.Service<MyService>();
}).Run();`